# How to play PCM data/buffer just using AVAudioPlayer or AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-audio, audiounit

How can i play PCM data/buffer just using AVAudioPlayer or AVPlayer ? I know, i can play PCM data/buffer using AudioUnit/AudioQueue by feeding the data into play callback method. But don't want to do this.

I have searched on google a lot but couldn't find any helpful answer or any sample code to do this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am answering my own question if it helps someone else. After few days of tireless trying, at last i have got it working. Though in a separate way. I have added a wav header info on top of RAW PCM data and saved a file with .wav extension. Then just play the file using AVAudioPlayer or AVPlayer.  Here you will get full sample code on [How to add playable(such as wav,wmv) header with PCM data/buffer in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231198/how-to-add-playablesuch-as-wav-wmv-header-with-pcm-data-buffer-in-ios)
ou.

Comment: Is there a way to set the AVAudioPlayer format externally and then write only the PCM samples? Android has something similar with the AudioTrack class...

Answer (score 2):

PCM data does not specify a readable format so AVPlayer will not be able to play it. You must save the PCM data into an audio file format that the player supports.